# Swift rendering curiosity, broken with "cocoa-touch" tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, syntax-highlighting

Look at

https://jsfiddle.net/amroamroamro/wm13afcv/

"#selector", working perfectly.

Notice ..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56995995/294884

Working fine.

Add the cocoa-touch tag, and reload - it breaks!

[image]

Remove cocoa-touch, reload - OK again.

Comment: Cocoa-touch has `lang-c` set as the highlighter. If any of the other tags have a different syntax configured then code will be marked up with the default highlighter which will result in “odd” choices for what constitutes a comment or a keyword in certain languages.

Comment: On that specific post, the `swift` tag has `lang-swift` configured. You can see what language is configured on the tag wiki pages.

Comment: The work-around is to add explicit language markers on your code blocks. See the duplicate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters (1) thanks, so it's  <!-- language: swift --> , great

Comment: @MartijnPieters (2) understood!  looking here stackoverflow.com/tags/cocoa-touch/info it has the wrong "Code Language" down the bottom.  ("lang-c" ... absolutely no connection at all to cocoa-touch)  I could not see how I can change it to lang-swift.  Is there a way?  Cheers

Comment: it may be that the [tag:cocoa-touch] should not *have* a syntax preference set. I don’t know enough about the subject area to make that call. That might be a valid Meta question to ask.

Comment: you're 1000% correct, cocoa-touch should *not* have a language preference set. it must and would inherit from either iOS, Swift or Objective-C.  Can I change it?

Comment: Us mods can make the change but I’d be wary of setting it to ‘swift’ if it once was the norm to be used almost exclusively with Objective-C. If that was the case I should not have a language set now that there is a mix of Objective-C and Swift use (ignoring post age)

Comment: And we mods prefer it if there was a separate dedicated meta post that requested the change. *Why was this changed?* -> *it was discussed here: meta link*.

Comment: yes, it's absolutely the case that it should not have one, it's just a library and is language neutral.  it would and can only inherit from the relevant language of the question.  (Sorry, above where I said "let's change it to Swift" I did not realize there was an option to have NO language override.)

Comment: Sounds like a shoe-in then! Easy Meta mana if you made that a new post :-)

Comment: thanks again (1) sure, happy to make a new post - i did so  (2) thanks